# What is the solution to this witness puzzle (spoiler)?

Tags: the-witness

[image]

I think the rule is: the number of triangles indicates how many edges you have to draw along.

Ignore the line I drew.

This occurred near the end of the music challenge section (in the maze like room). The puzzles are random there (but always solvable as far as I know), so I cannot get it back, but I am still curious.

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Hover to see solution:

> [image: Solution]

Generated using [The Windmill](https://windmill.thefifthmatt.com/12tpy1r)